# i am getting error on setting enttity to httppost . how

Tags: android, image, upload

## how to upload image to server using name value pair. This code not working when upload large images. i am getting error on before setting entity to httppost

---

```
     public void uploadImage(Bitmap bitmapImg, String session) {
    Log.d("mylog","constructing byte array stream object");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Log.d("mylog","compressing bimaph image");
    bitmapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
    Log.d("mylog","converting bitmap to byte array"+baos);
    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    Log.d("mylog","converting byte array to string "+b);
    String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d("mylog","constructing name value pair "+temp);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    Log.d("mylog","adding value to image in name value pair");
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("avatar",temp));
    Log.d("mylog","going to make request for upload image");
    json=jsonParser.getJsonForUpload("http://10.0.2.2/myweb/phototest.php","POST",nameValuePairs,session);
    Log.d("mylog","json parsed sucessfully "+json);
    jsonp=new JsonProvider(json);


}
```

---

```
    public JSONObject getJsonForUpload(String url, String method,
                                   final List<NameValuePair> params, final String session) {
    final String sess = session,Url=url;
    final List<NameValuePair> param = params;
    Log.d("mylog", "getjsonupload method called");
    try {

        Log.d("mylog", "inside try");
        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            Log.d("mylog", "inside post");

            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Url);
                        Log.d("mylog", "post setted going to set header");
                        httpPost.setHeader("CONTENT_TYPE", "MULTIPART/form-data");
                        httpPost.setHeader("ENCTYPE", "MULTIPART/form-data");
                        Log.d("mylog", "going to set entity");
```

> Blockquote after this the control skips to main task
>                               httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

```
                        Log.d("mylog", "going ton set connection time out");
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(cparams, 10000);
                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(cparams, 10000);
                        if (sess != null) {

                            Log.d("mylog", "going to set session id to header of post ");
                            Log.d("mylog", "the session PHPSESSID is" + sess);
                            httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=" + sess + ";");
                            Log.d("mylog", "header setted sucessfully");
                        }


                        Log.d("mylog", "going to execute client");
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        Log.d("mylog", "response obtained from the server sucessfully" + httpResponse);
                        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        String jsondata = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                        Log.d("mylog", "json parsing sucess " + jsondata);
                        jobj = new JSONObject(jsondata);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("mylog", "Error " + e);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("mylog", "error " + e);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("mylog", "Error " + e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("mylog", "Error " + e);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("mylog", "Error " + e);
                    }
                }
            };
            Log.d("mylog", "going to start thread");
            t.start();
            t.join();
            Log.d("mylog", "thread finished");


            if (session == null) {
                Log.d("mylog", "cookie not available ");
                Log.d("mylog", "going to obtain cooke from http response");
                try {
                    cookieStore = httpClient.getCookieStore();
                    iscooke = true;
                    Log.d("mylog", "cookie obtained sucessfully " + cookieStore);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("mylog", "error obtaining cookie" + cookieStore);
                }

                List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
                if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.d("mylog", "cookie is empty");
                } else {
                    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                        if (cookie.getName().equals("PHPSESSID")) {
                            sessionid = cookie.getValue();
                            Log.d("mylog", "session id successfully obtained " + sessionid);

                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("mylog", "cookie store already available ");
            }


        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("mylog", "Error " + e);
    }

    // return JSON String
    Log.d("mylog", "json from json object is " + jobj);
    return jobj;

}
```

Comment: you are using base64string to upload image which is not suitable for large image uploading as its string will become very large, and it may throw error

Answer (score 0):

try this code to upload image, you can upload large image with this code

```
try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "YOUR WEB SERVICE URL");
        entity = getMultipleEntityUpload();
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                httpContext);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();

        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        is));

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line);
    }
    String result =total.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

private MultipartEntity getMultipleEntityUpload() {
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //imagePic is bitmap of your image      
    imagePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] arrByteImage = stream.toByteArray();
        try {
        entity.addPart(WS_Key_Constant.KEY_IMAGE, new ByteArrayBody(
                arrByteImage, ".jpg"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return entity;
}
```